# C# AND assignment operator (&=) with bitwise enums

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators

I am using a bitwise enum to return a value from a function

```
[Flags]
private enum PatientRecord { NoRecord=0x0, SameEnrollmentDate=0x1, SameScreeningDate=0x2 }
```

and have a function with

```
var returnVar = PatientRecord.NoRecord;
....
if (condition...)
{
   returnVar &= PatientRecord.SameEnrollmentDate;
}
return returnVar
```

The debugger is showing that returnVar has the same value before and after the [AND assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx) has executed (be that PatientRecord.NoRecord (0) or PatientRecord.SameScreeningDate (2)).

why is this, and are there any solutions neater than:

```
returnVar = returnVar & PatientRecord.SameEnrollmentDate;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want bitwise OR (`|`) rather than bitwise AND (`&`):

```
var returnVar = PatientRecord.NoRecord;
....
if (condition...)
{
   returnVar |= PatientRecord.SameEnrollmentDate;
   //        ^ Bitwise OR assignment
}
```

AND'ing with zero (`NoRecord=0x0`) will always result in zero.

Comment: of course - i wonder if I can downvote my own answer for silliest SO question ever (I have had a long day, so please move along people, nothing to see here) - thanks.

Comment: sometimes the obvious escapes us when having looked at the code for a long time.